# computing flux integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

just given this question. compute the flux out of the unit circle, C. $$F(x,y)=\langle x+2y,3x+4y\rangle $$

i am not sure on how to solve this. Usually the flux would include Z function. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 2-dimensional flux. Evaluate
$$\int_C{\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\,ds=\int_0^{2\pi}<\cos(t)+2\sin(t),3\cos(t)+4\sin(t)>\cdot<\cos(t),\sin(t)>dt\\
=\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^2(t)+10\sin(t)\cos(t)+ 4\sin^2(t))dt=\pi+0+4\pi=5\pi.$$
Note that by the [planar divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem#Relationship_to_the_divergence_theorem), the same result can be obtained by evaluating
$$\int_D (F_x+F_y)dxdy=\int_D (1+4)dxdy=5|D|=5\pi.$$
where $D$ is the unit disc.

Answer (score 0):

The flux of $F(x,y)$ across $C$ is given by $\int_C F(x,y)\cdot n\,ds$, where $n$ is the outward normal vector to $C$. Using the planar divergence theorem, you could also calculate this integral as:
$$\int_C F(x,y)\cdot n\,ds=\iint_D\nabla\cdot F(x,y)\,dA$$
Where $D$ is enclosed by $C$ (in this case $D$ is the unit disk).

Answer (score 0):

Or using the great Gauss (divergence) theorem:

$$\nabla f=1+4=5\implies \iint_C\vec F\cdot\vec n\,d\vec s=\iint_R\nabla fdA=5\iint_RdA=5\cdot\pi\cdot1^2=5\pi$$